# Strange usage of std::map constructor

Tags: c++, stl

I searched for an implementation of std::map runtime ordering and have found this solution:
[STL std::map dynamic ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457679/stl-stdmap-dynamic-ordering)

It is clear for me, but I don't understand, how it can be possible to use OrderingType in the constructor of std::map. std::map has a constructor, which gets a comparator object as an argument. So it is normal from my point of view to use code like this:

```
int main()
{
   Ordering<int> test_ordering( ASCENDING );   
   CUSTOMMAP map1( test_ordering );

   return 0;
}
```

But code from above mentioned topic also compiles:

```
int main()
{
   CUSTOMMAP map1( ASCENDING );
   //...
   return 0;
}
```

I don't understand, why it works: constructor of std::map must not get argument of OrderingType enumeration instead of Ordering class object itself.

Comment: I don't see a `std::map` anywhere in this picture.

Comment: I've just taken a block of code from the topic mentioned above. Perhaps, I should have quoted it entirely. I don't know, if it is better than only to leave a link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the constructor on `Ordering<int>` that takes your enumeration isn't declared as `explicit`, then it is considered a "conversion constructor" that can automatically be inserted when the compiler has a need to convert from your enumeration type to the `Ordering<int>` type. So the compiler is effectively taking this:

```
CUSTOMMAP map1( ASCENDING );
```

and transforming it into this:

```
CUSTOMMAP map1( Ordering<int>(ASCENDING) );
```

This is called an **implicit conversion**.